# How to trigger textBox_KeyPress on formload event

Tags: c#, winforms

i have 2 forms for this process, Frm1 which i input qty and hit enter btn, Frm2 will open captured the qty inputted from Frm1, in my Frm2 i have a textbox1_keypress event using enter button on kb to process the transaction and the data will throw back to Frm1 dgv using button1 of Frm2.
my question is how i can trigger the textBox_keypress event of Frm2 formload it is possible? if yes how.. thanks in advance

```
private void textBox2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == 13)
        {
         //transaction process here
         this.button1_Click(sender, e);//perform click after user by hit enter frm kb Frm1
        }
    }
```

perform textbox_keypress

```
private void FrM_Edit_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.textbox_keypress();
    }
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do. Can you clarify? What you have posted will NOT work. When you call `this.dataGridView1_CellMouseClick(null,null);` (which is awkward) … then `DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e` will be null… therefore, even if there are rows in the grid… `e.RowIndex >= 0` will fail with a null exception since `e` is null.

Comment: @JohnG, my apology,

Comment: It is unclear what you are wanting to do. It does not make a lot of sense to fire form2’s text box “keypress” event in the form2 load event. Technically, in the form2 load event, the text box has yet to be displayed to the user, so firing the text boxes key press event seems odd. From what I can decipher, you have two forms and on form1 it has a text box. Through some event I assume a button click, form2 is created and the text from the form1 text box is passed to the new form2. Then form2 is displayed. After that I am not sure what you want.

Comment: @Jhong thankyou for your comment, after passing the data to form2 txtbox, the txtbox of form2 has this textbox_keypress event that will process the transaction(has already working code) using kb and the form2 is showing, i want to fire the textbox_keypress event in formload so that the form2 will not show on the user..

Comment: Hmmm… your comment… _”i want to fire the textbox_keypress event in formload so that the form2 will not show on the user"_ ? … Then what is the purpose of form2? From form1, why not simply _”process the transaction”_ and pass it to the _”already working code”_ ? I feel like there is something pertinent missing in your question.